# Getting the values of a variable from other file - PHP

Tags: php, include, require

I need to get the value of a variable which is present in another file. I know I can use the include or the require function but in both the cases it prints out the entire output which is present in the file which was included. So is there a way around to get only the values of the variables and not the output from another file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ob_start();
include($filename);
ob_end_clean();
```

Your variable should now be available in scope.

Of course if you care about the output, you may want to keep it:

```
ob_start();
include($filename);
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

This is with the caveat that you should never do this if you are the designer of the whole app. Instead, set up all the variables in one file and use a separate one to generate output. Ideally look into an MVC architecture where the controller sets the variables and view/template does the output.

Comment: Good point. I'm assuming that this would be part of a library or something where the file cannot be changed. That this is a bad architecture should be obvious, but still worth pointing out.

Comment: Yes, it is being executed but ideally you would want to be able to do one thing (set up variables) without unintended side-effects (outputting anything). Is it your file or someone else's?

Answer (score 0):

The following can do it:

```
ob_start();
include(...);
ob_end_clean();
```

ob_start() begins output buffering, where nothing is sent to the browser/cli/etc. Include your file. Variables within the file will be available, and all echo, etc will not display.

ob_end_clean() will dump the buffer, as in erase, and will not display the information while freeing memory.

Answer (score 0):

Take that value and put it in a third file. `include` that file in your files 1 and 2.

In other words, improve the structure of your application so it's possible to access what you need to access separately.